# How do multi-parameter linq expression initialize their parameter?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102661/compare-two-list-elements-with-linq) the solution to the problem is:

`list.Where((item, index) => index < list.Count - 1 && list[index + 1] == item)`

The concept of multi-parameter (ie `(item, index)`) is a bit puzzling to me and I don't know the correct word to narrow down my google results. So 1) What is that called? And more importantly, 2) How are the non-enumerable variable initialize?  In this case how is `index` compiled as an int and initialized to 0?

Thanks.

Comment: note that you had `item` and `index` reversed; it looks like that has been fixed by an edit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Lambda expressions have various syntax options:

```
() => ... // no parameters
x => ... // single parameter named x, compiler infers type
(x) => ... // single parameter named x, compiler infers type
(int x) => ... // single parameter named x, explicit type
(x, y) => ... // two parameters, x and y; compiler infers types
(int x, string y) => ... // two parameters, x and y; explicit types
```

The subtlety here is that `Where` has an overload that accepts a `Func<T, int, bool>`, representing the *value* and *index* respectively (and returning the `bool` for the match). So it is the `Where` implementation that supplies the index - something like:

```
static class Example
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
        Func<T, int, bool> predicate)
    {
        int index = 0;
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            if (predicate(item, index++)) yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to initialize index to something other than 0?

Comment: @Edward in the core implementation? no. But you could just add a fixed number to `index` in the expression, i.e. `list[index + offset]`. In a custom implementation you could do anything you like, but I'm not sure of the wisdom / need / etc.

Answer (score 4):

When using LINQ, remember that you are passing a method delegate to the `Where` method. The particular overload of `Where` that you are invoking takes a method with signature `Func<T,int,bool>`, and will call this method for each item in `list`. Internally, this particular method is keeping count for every item iterated, and calling the supplied delegate using this value as the second parameter:

```
var result=suppliedDelegate(item,count)
```

Comment: This also applies to `Select` method in LINQ

Answer (score 2):

This answer's a little more technical...  Remember that lambdas are simply syntatic shortcuts to anonymous delegates (which are anonymous methods).
**Edit:** They can also be expression trees depending on the signature of `Where` (see Marc's comment).

```
list.Where((item, index) => index < list.Count - 1 && list[index + 1] == item)
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
// inline, no lambdas
list.Where(delegate(item, index) { return index < list.Count - 1 && list[index + 1] == item; });

// if we assign the lambda (delegate) to a local variable:
var lambdaDelegate = (item, index) => index < list.Count - 1 && list[index + 1] == item;

list.Where(lambdaDelegate);

// without using lambdas as a shortcut:
var anonymousDelegate = delegate(item, index)
    {
        return index < list.Count - 1 && list[index + 1] == item;
    }

list.Where(anonymousDelegate);

// and if we don't use anonymous methods (which is what lambdas represent):
function bool MyDelegate<TSource>(TSource item, int index)
{
    return index < list.Count - 1 && list[index + 1] == item;
}

list.Where(MyDelegate);
```

The `Where` method has the following signature:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
delegate bool WhereDelegate<TSource>(TSource source, int index);
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, WhereDelegate<TSource> predicate);
```

That's where the item and index are defined.

Behind the scenes, `Where` may do something like (just a guess, you can decompile to see):

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate)
{
    int index = 0;

    foreach (TSource item in source)
    {
        if (predicate(index, source))
             yield return item;

        index++;
    }
}
```

So that's where index is initialized and gets passed to your delegate (anonymous, lambda, or otherwise).

Comment: "Remember that lambdas are simply syntatic shortcuts to anonymous delegates" is not true; they *can* be anonymous methods, but they could also be expression trees. There is no way to predict which unless you know the `Where` signature, which is *usually* determined by the data-source, i.e. what `list` is in the first code example in your post.

Comment: @Marc: You're right.  Whether it's an expression tree or anonymous method, the comparisons are still identical, so the result is the same.  So are expression trees typically faster since the whole tree can become one delegate (less on the stack, etc.)?   And of course if you're dealing with LINQ to SQL, it ends up becoming SQL, not necessarily a delegate.